# How to pass window and string parameter from code behind into User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a bit off header that I need global to a few files so I have made a user control (I can't use the main window as this isn't global to all files) however there's two parameters that my user control needs, `ScreenName` and `MainWindow` to navigate on the home button click. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public Header(MainWindow mainWindow, string screenName)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        ScreenName = screenName;
        MainWindow = mainWindow;
        ScreenNameTextBlock.Text = ScreenName;
    }

    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    public MainWindow MainWindow { get; set; }

    private void Hyperlink_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //need to navigate home here
        MainWindow.LoadScreenByCode("Menu");
    }
```

You can probably assume the corresponding XAML as it's just a hyperlink and a textblock, but if you need it let me know.

I can include the user control like so:

```
<controls:Header x:Name="Header"></controls:Header>
```

But I can't figure out how to assign the parameters. If I try in the codebehind I can access the values like this:

```
Header.MainWindow = Shell;
Header.ScreenName = "Name";
```

But this causes the values to be null. Sorry if this is an easy issue, I am new to UserControls.

Comment: I would look info Binding and DependencyProperties, and what role they play in WPF.

Comment: @GEEF I understand binding but not DependencyProperties. Is it just me or is the support/documentation for WPF severely lacking? Here's the documentation for DependencyProperties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the main window of your application you should get the running instance of it as the following:

```
     MainWindow myRunnningMainWindow = (Application.Current.MainWindow as MainWindow);

     if(myRunningWindow!=null)
        {
         //Do what you want with the main window
        }
```

Comment: You can access the main window from anywhere in your application using that line of code. If you want a cleaner version of this in your made up property you can write it as the following :